# Setting New Compound Structure for WallType Does not Update LayerID of CompoundStructureLayers

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

1)I have a WallType and need to Change the compound structure of WallType.

```
   private void updateCompoundStructure(WallType wT)
{
  IList<Autodesk.Revit.DB.CompoundStructureLayer> csl = new     List<Autodesk.Revit.DB.CompoundStructureLayer>();

   csl.Add(new Autodesk.Revit.DB.CompoundStructureLayer()
                                {
                                    DeckEmbeddingType = deck,
                                    DeckProfileId = profileId,
                                    Function = structureFunction,
                                    LayerCapFlag = item.LayerCapFlag,
                                    MaterialId = materialId,
                                    Width = item.Thickness
                                });

CompoundStructure cs = CompoundStructure.CreateSimpleCompoundStructure(csl);
if (cs.IsValid(dbDoc, out IDictionary<int, CompoundStructureError> errMap, out IDictionary<int, int> twoLayerErrorMap))
                        {
                            wallType.SetCompoundStructure(cs);
                        }
}
```

The walltype compound structure is updated properly

But,CompoundStructureLayer.LayerId is the read-only field we cannot update it
for all the CompoundStructureLayer's LayerId I get is like 0

2) when i read the compoundStructure form WallType it  gives LayerID as at 0 th index as 0,

at 1 st  index as 1

at 2nd inndex as 2... and so on

is there any way to Update The layerID of compound Structure?
is there any workaround to achive that.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/7b6ace8a-7810-5e6d-760e-642361fbe916.htm) no. The layerId does not provide a setter. Maybe reword your question with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there any workaround to achieve that?

Comment: No. I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Why are you trying to update the `layerId`?

Comment: I need to find the core layer of CompoundStructure we can achieve this by
cs.IsCoreLayer() function and it accept index or LayerID to determine the core layers.

Comment: Can you not use `GetFirstCoreLayerIndex` or `GetLastCoreLayerIndex`?

Comment: Thanks for an idea, I will try it out. do you have sample related to that some thing.

Comment: @Scrobi  can you please provide a sample for GetFirstCoreLayerIndex example?

Comment: see the usage in this blog [post](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/03/updating-wall-compound-layer-structure.html)